# SQL Server Reporting Services Reporting Services Tree Navigation with out iframe in mvc application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Work on SQL Server Reporting Services. Service url is **http://xxxx/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx** . To show this service in my mvc application I used **iframe**

**Syntax is bellow**

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" name="Main" height="400" width="1200" src=" http://xxxx/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx" frameborder="0" />
```

It’s work perfectly,but with out iframe want to show service report in mvc application.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid an iframe with

```
<object data="http://server/reportserver/..." width="100%" height="800px" ></object>
```

Comment: ,thanks for your reply,i have no problem with iframe/object ,problem is want to process iframe work on C# code.Looking for some syntax in C# which can do same work like iFrame.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Note you have more control over the report if you use the server/reportserver url than if you embed the server/reports url as you can pass parameters in the url and control rendering